# Ruby FFI, how to include library in Gem

Tags: ruby, deployment, shared-libraries, ffi

From what I've learned there are different ways to include a library in a Ruby-FFI powered gem.
1) Put all the sourcecode in the gem and compile using ffi-compile
2) Assume lib is installed on the system already
3) Ship the .so with the gem?

In our case the library is quite large and hard to compile. How should we include this into the Gem? It should be easy to deploy for other people to as it is opensource.